# windows service, can't have network access until user logon

Tags: windows, sockets

I am trying to write a simple window service on window 7 64bit. The user account for the service is LocalSystem.

What I want to do is just a basic server/client socket program and the server exists in a windows service. The service just does a simple thing. When it starts, it creates a thread to listen on a port and wait for client connecting using window socket apis. **But the problem is the client can't connect to the server until a user login the machine on which the service is running.**

Below is my code for installing the service.

```c
wchar_t szPath[MAX_PATH];
SC_HANDLE schSCManager = NULL;
SC_HANDLE schService = NULL;

GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath);
schSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
schService = CreateService(
    schSCManager,
    L"msdcontrol",
    L"msd control",
    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,
    SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
    SERVICE_AUTO_START,
    SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
    szPath,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is the service actually installed and running?

Comment: Can the client machine ping the server machine when a user isn't logged in?  In some enterprises, the network is configured to block access unless a user is logged in.  There might also be third-party firewalls that change the rules depending on who is logged in.

Comment: I checked. The service has been installed successfully. It can start when the machine boot-up.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yes, you are right. I can't ping the server machine until a user login. I am checking the configuration of the firewall. This might be the root cause. Thank you!

Comment: The issue has been resolved now. The root cause is the server machine uses corporate wifi, and the wifi network can't be connected until the user login.